# Font metrics for a Windows Universal app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have been trying for some time now to find the APIs in Windows 10 that would provide me all the information about font metrics I would need when developing a Universal App in C#.

The real problem I'm trying to solve is to draw text along a path. I already have code in place to identify the coordinates of a given point given a given distance along the path. What I currently lack is the ability to identify the proper distance between characters.

I'd also like to know the typeface characteristics such as leading, trailing, ascent, descent, etc... I believe that TextFormatter is no longer available or possibly, I don't know how to access it.

Can anyone help me by providing either an example or preferably the correct Microsoft documentation for the class I would need.

Thank you

Comment: You tagged the question with both `wpf` and `win-universal-app`, are you really interested in a wpf answer?

Comment: Take a look at Win2D's text features: https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/wiki/Features

Comment: m-y thanks for asking. I am not entirely sure I tagged this appropriately as at this point, I imagine that WPF and universal would handle this the same way. Though I suppose I could be wrong.

Comment: There is a CanvasFontFace class which has those metrics. Now, if I can only figure out how to get a CanvasFontFace object . . .

Comment: I've found a couple of sources of CanvasFontFace objects. CanvasFontSet has a whole list of them. And CanvasScaledFont owns a CanvasFontFace. I think the real deal would be to get a CanvasScaledFont from somewhere and work from that. But I still can't figure out where one can get one.

Answer (score 0):

The following works. It is hacky as hell, and I'm sure there is a better way. If you need the CanvasFontFace objects often, you had better cache them, as this is not a fast getter. Once you have the CanvasFontFace object, you can use it to find ascent, descent, etc.

```
public static CanvasFontFace FindFontFace() {
  // Very hacky . . . there has to be a better way . . .
  CanvasFontFace r = null;
  CanvasFontSet set = CanvasFontSet.GetSystemFontSet();
  string fontFaceName = "Regular"; // change to your face . . .
  string familyName = "Segoe UI"; // change to your family . . . 
  IReadOnlyList<CanvasFontFace> allFaces = set.Fonts;
  string key = "en-us";
  foreach (CanvasFontFace face in allFaces) {
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> faceNames = face.FaceNames;
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> familyNames = face.FamilyNames;
    if (faceNames.ContainsKey(key)) {
      if (familyNames.ContainsKey(key)) {
        if (faceNames[key] == fontFaceName) {
          if (familyNames[key] == familyName) {
            r = face;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // if r is null, you probably have an incorrect face name or family name.
  return r;
}
```